# Scope generation in directive template does't work with transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How to define a directive in Angularjs that **gets parameters** and transcludes sub-elements with **ngIf or ngRepeat**?

A full demonstration of the problem can be found here - http://jsfiddle.net/2aa47/4/. Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
    <my-directive condition="flag">
        Both 'flag' and 'a' are defined on controller's scope.
        Hi. {{a}} -> Nothing is shown after 'Hi'.
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

And the script. In my real problem I have significantly larger template that has ngIf in the middle.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { condition: '=condition' },
        template: '<div ng-if="condition" ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

In order to get parameters directive an isolated scope should be created. Both ngIf, ngRepeat and other similar directives will create a scope that inherites from that isolated scope. Then transcluded elements will get scope sibling to the later, meaning directly under directive's isolated one:

```
Controller's scope
  Directive's isolated scope
    Scope created by ngIf
    Element transcluded by directive. Should be directly under controller's scope
```

Now transcluded elements inside the directive can't access the controller's scope. How to mitigate this?

For the reference, there's such an issue on Angular project - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1809.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've plunked a workaround for this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cw2TDJ?p=preview).

By injecting `setTransscope` into your directive and calling it in the linking phase, the correct scope is marked for transcluding. Instead of using the `ng-transclude` directive in the template, the `ng-transscope` directive should be used, which restores the earlier marked scope.

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(setTransscope) {
  return {
    scope: {
      display: "="
    },
    transclude: true,   // required
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
    link: setTransscope

    /* ... or call within your own link function:
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      setTransscope($scope, $element);

      // ...
      // Other stuff
      // ...
    } */

  };
});
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-if="display">
  <div ng-transscope></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Tested - http://jsfiddle.net/2aa47/10/. I only had problem with call to `$element.empty();`. For some reason `empty` was underfined. Directive apparently worked without it. And scope dumper seems to be a powerful and simple debugging tool.